# C++ - Mail Sender

Tags: c++, email, function, sender

I would like to create a mail sender on C++ (not Mail Client for eg. GMail). In this mailer I want to be able to change the headers also.

I have already downloaded and installed the POCO libraries, that might help (I found it on a similar anwser).

For example, what I would like is a command like below:

```
e-mailsend(to,headers,subject,message);
// Or something like:
email.send(to,headers,subject,message);
```

However, If possible, I would like to use a C++ Mail function not a system function (like mail-utils in unix).

*If you need any more explanation please comment...*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210/c-smtp-example

Comment: Your question should be what libraries you could use for that task. C++ by itself does not have such functionality. I don't know such a library though. Maybe use Google.

Comment: OK! I will test the First comment's option and I will reply If it does what I need...

Comment: As I read the code again, I noticed that this requires an SMTP Server. Isn't there any option without SMTP? A standalone sender maybe?

Comment: @akatzbreaker how should the communication work then?

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you asked for an option without an SMTP server.

SMTP requires an SMTP Server. The choice is that could send emails directly (e.g. to joe at yahoo.com on port 25) or to a SMTP server that will relay the message.

Ideally, you will want your own SMTP server locally (so your application is simpler and your SMTP server sends the messages in the background, handles retries, bounces and connection errors) and use a reputable SMTP service or an existing email account.

1. If you want to send spam, I'd strongly advise against it.
2. If you want to send a small number of messages that will be opened by people expecting those messages, use a normal account (Yahoo, GMail, Google Apps, etc) and if you find your application not responsive enough, install Postfix, Sendmail or whatever local SMTP server you like.
3. If you want to send a large volume of emails and you are sure those message won't get you targeted as a spammer, use an SMTP service, like SendGrid (note: they also have a web API that you might find easier to use than SMTP).

Depending on which of the above you need, I'm sure answering your original question with a recommendation for SMTP C++ clients (like POCO) with become simpler.

Comment: Are you aware whether it is possible to send email from Poco without any valid sender email details (like SMTP server name, password, etc)? SendGrid does it, it behaves as a SMTP server itself, so it is possible to send emails from code using even a non-existing email address..